# Micro-Frontend and Composite UI - Difference?

Tags: html, microservices, micro-frontend

I'm pretty new to the whole 'microservices' subject and started reading something about Composite UI's.

Now my question is, is there a difference between Composite UI's and Micro-Frontends? Or does it basically describe the same thing?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

you can find a nice description here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/microservice-based-composite-ui-shape-layout

i m not expert in microservices but  I understand    that composite UI  consists of using  several frontend microservice on the  same UI (like a dashboard of frontend  ...)
[image]